# How to insert a record with LINQ and C# and return the Primary Key of that record

Tags: c#, linq

What's the best way to write a LINQ query that inserts a record and then returns the primary key of that newly inserted record using C# ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The primary key value will be in that property after the SubmitChanges().

```
MyTable record = new MyTable();
record.Name = "James Curran";
db.MyTable.InsertOnSubmit(record);
db.SubmitChanges();
Console.WriteLine("record inserted as ID : {0}", record.Id);
```

Comment: There's a typo on line 3, it should read InsertOnSubmit(record)

Comment: InsertOnSubmit() didn't work. db.MyTable.Add(record);

Answer (score 6):

```
// Create a new Order object.
Order ord = new Order
{
    OrderID = 12000,
    ShipCity = "Seattle",
    OrderDate = DateTime.Now
    // …
};

// Add the new object to the Orders collection.
db.Orders.InsertOnSubmit(ord);

// Submit the change to the database.
try
{
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    // Make some adjustments.
    // ...
    // Try again.
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
return ord.OrderID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Any field with AutoGeneratedValue=true will be filled in after that record is submitted to the database by dc.SubmitChanges()